# Adding oembed plugin to 2amigos ckeditor widget in yii2

Tags: php, ckeditor, yii2, oembed

I'm trying to add the oembed plugin to ckeditor via the 2amigos widget for yii2.

I did the following, but can't seem to get the button to appear:

1. I downloaded and copied the oembed and widget plugins to the ckeditor plugins folder
2. I set the clientOptions for the widget in my form using the code below:

   ```
   $form->field($theComment, 'comment')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
       'clientOptions' => ['config.extraPlugins' => 'widget,oembed'],
       'options' => ['rows' => 6],
       'preset' => 'full'
   ])
   ```
3. I altered the full.php preset filworkinge by adding the following lines of code below:

   ```
   'toolbarGroups' => [
       ['name' => 'document', 'groups' => ['mode', 'document', 'doctools']],
       ['name' => 'clipboard', 'groups' => ['clipboard', 'undo']],
       ['name' => 'editing', 'groups' => [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker']],
       ['name' => 'forms'],
       '/',
       ['name' => 'basicstyles', 'groups' => ['basicstyles', 'colors','cleanup']],
       ['name' => 'paragraph', 'groups' => [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ]],
       ['name' => 'links'],
       ['name' => 'insert'],
       '/',
       ['name' => 'styles'],
       ['name' => 'blocks'],
       ['name' => 'colors'],
       ['name' => 'tools'],
       ['name' => 'others'],
       '/',            //added by me
       ['name' => 'oembed'],   //added by me
   ],
   ```

Not entirely sure if the error is in my edit to clientOptions, or in my edit to toolbarGroups, or both!.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

plugin add in assets folder (example plugin spoiler) zarnica.dev\www\assets\dff59c5c\plugins\spoiler

```
<script>CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'spoiler';</script>
```

DONE!